# Java Stream function usage

Tags: java

So in my game, if the player uses an item on the item #2 which is stored in an enum, i want to use the java Stream function and find the usage to call as seen below this is what I want to do/attempt.

```
if (itemUsed == TINDERBOX && useWith == FiremakingData.getLog(useWith).get().getLog()) {
    FiremakingData.DATA_SET.stream().forEach(log -> {
        FiremakingData.getLog(useWith).get().executeFire(player, useWith);
    });
}
```

The null pointer line is

```
if (itemUsed == TINDERBOX && useWith == FiremakingData.getLog(useWith).get().getLog()) {
```

This is my stream method

```
public static Optional<FiremakingData> getLog(int log)
{
    return DATA_SET.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).filter(logData -> logData.getLog() == log).findFirst();
}
```

The code should be pretty straight forward on what i'm trying to do, however it sends a nullpointer when trying to perform the action or use the tinderbox on any other item i use it on. Please help me find the proper usage! thanks so much guys/girls!

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? This is usually the best method to get an idea on what exactly is going on. From the snippets you posted I think only `DATA_SET` might be null. Are you sure this is properly initialized?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.